# How can I push the same ViewController more than once?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nib

I have a list and I want to show it 3 times (from one list to the other when I click on a specific cell). For that I'm using a XIB containing my ListView. I've also set up a NavigationController to have the push animation.

This is how I call the pushViewController method in my rootViewController.

```
    case "Groupe" :
        //this is OK since it's the first time I push the ViewController
        service.getGroupe()
        let vueGroupe = vueListe!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vueGroupe, animated: true)
        vueListe.navigationItem.title = "Groupe View";
    case "Categorie" :
        //this is not
        let vueCat = vueListe!
        service.getCategorie(ids: elem!)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vueCat, animated: true)
        vueListe.navigationItem.title = "Groupe View";
```

With this code I get the following error :

> "Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported"

How can I push the same ViewController more than once ?

Comment: Looks like it says it right in the error.... *"Pushing the same view controller **instance** more than one..."*. (Emphasis intended.) Just create another instance of your view controller. And yes, to me it appears to be bad design - either use the same view controller and separate views (not controllers), or something else. One last hint - if you *really* need most of your VC logic to be shared among three similar controllers, look into (1) removing that code into a shared Framework target and (2) subclassing your controller into three separate ones - your shouldn't get any errors that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new instance of the `UIViewController` object and push it.

So, in your code it will be something like:

```
case "Groupe":
    service.getGroupe()
    let vueGroupe = VueListeViewController() // I would create a new view controller here as well
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vueGroupe, animated: true)
    vueListe.navigationItem.title = "Groupe View";
case "Categorie":
    let vueCat = VueListeViewController() // New instance
    service.getCategorie(ids: elem!)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vueCat, animated: true)
    vueListe.navigationItem.title = "Groupe View";
```

Comment: I had to change my delegates but it was part of the solution, thanks !